# Cannot use multiple database when using commands in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, multiple-databases

I am using multiple database connection in my system(Yii 2). db and db2, db2 connection is from another database server.

Its run smoothly when im use it normally(in controller). but when i am using it in commands i got this error

[image]

i have this in my code

web.php

```
 $db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';
 $db2 = require __DIR__ . '/db2.php';

    'components' => [
    'db' => $db,
            'db2' => $db2,
],
```

db.php

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=attendance',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',

    // Schema cache options (for production environment)
    'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    'schemaCacheDuration' => 60,
    'schemaCache' => 'cache',
];
```

db2.php

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=10.50.0.161;dbname=xxx',
    'username' => 'xxx',
    'password' => 'xxxx',
    'charset' => 'utf8',

    // Schema cache options (for production environment)
    'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    'schemaCacheDuration' => 60,
    'schemaCache' => 'cache',
];
```

Tblprcobiodata.php

```
class Tblprcobiodata extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface {

    // add the function below:
    public static function getDb() {
        return Yii::$app->get('db2'); // second database
    }
```

commands/KehadiranController.php

```
public function actionTest() {
    $biodata = Tblprcobiodata::findAll(['DeptId' => 137]);


    foreach ($biodata as $bio) {
        echo $bio->CONm . '-' . TblRekod::totalSalah($bio->ICNO, 02);
    }

    return ExitCode::OK;
}
```

Comment: you are missing the config in the `console/config.php` file in your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add db2.php to console.php as well. That is the config that is loaded during console commands (as you can se [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/yii)).